# GOS attachments download

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Basically I have some attachments listed in the Generic Object Services (GOS) and I need to download all of them to my computer.

I need to know how do download these attachments programatically from my program/report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never actually had to do this myself, but I think this is how it's done:

Get the list of attachments by calling `cl_binary_relation=>read_links` passing in the `ID` of the object that the attachments are attached to. The it_relation_options table should be filled with a relation like so:

```
la_relat-sign = 'I'.
la_relat-option = 'EQ'.
la_relat-low = 'ATTA'.     "Attachements
APPEND la_relat TO lt_relat.
```

This tells read_links to get the related objects classed as attachments.

Once you've successfully got the attachment details, you should be able to loop over the results table and pass each to the `SO_OBJECT_READ` function module (if that doesn't work try `SO_DOCUMENT_READ_API1`). This expects a folder id and a document id; in the results of read_links these may be concatenated together into one string (with the object type, e.g. `SOFM` at the front).

`SO_OBJECT_READ` will give you the binary content. You can then call `SO_OBJECT_DOWNLOAD` with (I think) `filetype = 'BIN'`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: To select only certain attachments you can query the SGTBREL table, then extract the necessary keys from the instid_b field to query the SOOD (SAP Office Object Definition) table, to obtain fields like file size, extension, and description. Then search for the attachments in the so3c table, from which you can obtain the necessary information to finally use the SO_OBJECT_DOWNLOAD function.